# Issue running ga.read_ga from iPython

Tags: python, google-analytics, ipython, google-api-python-client

I've run into issues running code from iPython notebook. This is the code ran:

```
import pandas.io.ga as ga
import gflags

df = ga.read_ga(['visits', 'avgTimeOnSite'], 
                         dimensions=['date', 'hour'], 
                         start_date='2012-10-25')
```

And this is the resulting error:

```
C:\Users\bdoherty\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\auth.pyc in authenticate(flow, storage)
    106     credentials = storage.get()
    107     if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
--> 108         credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage)
    109 
    110     http = credentials.authorize(http)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
```

Looking at the source code for auth.py there is no function run() defined but there is a run_flow function, what is the issue here and why is it trying to call run(). Apologies in advance if this is an obvious question, only getting started with GA and python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the the [deprecated run() function was removed on Aug 25](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/commit/05ae3426f271515bab4dc6a210428300286438e8) from the library pandas was using.

Pandas needs to update their code to make use of the replacement:
    tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)

If you have a working testing environment with the pandas repository you probably could put in a successful pull request making use of [this method](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/blob/master/oauth2client/tools.py#L115).

Alternatively you could checkout an older version of the the oauth2client.

Answer (score 0):

Either file a ticket with the owners of Pandas to change (currently) line 108 of [pandas/io/auth.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/1d8717446d8666207b63ae324e56be60a0b01b07/pandas/io/auth.py) from `run()` to `run_flow()`, or make the fix yourself and file a PR.

For other developers running into this error: If you have the latest version ([as of Feb 2016](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/1d8717446d8666207b63ae324e56be60a0b01b07/pandas/io/auth.py)) of the [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/commit/98df500a29157ccaa3f6bdf4517d57a5be8e85f1), just **rename** your call from `tools.run()` to `tools.run_flow()`, and you should be good-to-go. More about this change in a PSA (public service announcement) [blogpost](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python) I wrote back in mid-2015 but update periodically to stay current.

The fastest way to upgrade your Client Library is with:
`pip install -U google-api-python-client  # or pip3 for 3.x`